# retrieve POST data from FLASH to ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, actionscript, post

here's my AS3 code:

```
var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/patients/webcam.aspx");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_self");
```

And here's my ASP.Net Code

```
try
            {
                string pt = Path.Combine(PathFolder, "test.jpg");
                HttpFileCollection fileCol = Request.Files;
                Response.Write(fileCol.Count.ToString());
                foreach (HttpPostedFile hpf in fileCol)
                {
                    hpf.SaveAs(pt);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
```

I'm getting a weird error, HttpFox mentioned: "NS_ERROR_NET_RESET"

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to catch an http post file from Flash to ASP.Net page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634974/how-to-catch-an-http-post-file-from-flash-to-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the contentType to multipart/form-data if you want to
use c# Request.Files property.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx

Also it requires some changes in flash code, as the data should be encoded in MIME multipart format.

Comment: hello!

is it a "multipart/form-data" content type?

im still having trouble receiving the data, though the HttpFox gives me the content length, my c# code doesn't get the right value. it just says 0.

Comment: I think you need to encode somehow the data, you can not directly send the binary data

Comment: That encoding is not easy, I recommend you to look into third party classes in order to do it like MultipartURLLoader:

http://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/source/browse/trunk/projects/MultipartURLLoader/ru/inspirit/net/MultipartURLLoader.as